# How do I close my program correctly in C++?

Tags: c++, function, return, call

I am writing one of my first programs which reads from a file and allows you to play a game, I have been told the **exit** function is not a good idea.

I am trying to call back to main in order to close the program correctly but I get the following error:

C3861 'main': identifier not found.

any ideas where I went wrong or how I can properly call the main function?

**Code Below:**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void extra() {
    int lives = 3;
    int UI, intAnswer;
    int opt = 0;
    string IN, NoQ, q, c1, c2, c3, Answer;
    fstream quiz;
    cout << "Welcome to the guessing game!" << endl;
    quiz.open("QuizQuestions.txt");
    getline(quiz, IN);
    cout << "There are " << IN << " Questions" << endl;
    while (quiz.good() && opt !=2) {
        getline(quiz, q);
        cout << "Question " << q << endl;
        getline(quiz, c1);
        cout << c1 << endl;
        getline(quiz, c2);
        cout << c2 << endl;
        getline(quiz, c3);
        cout << c3 << endl;
        getline(quiz, Answer);
        intAnswer = stoi(Answer);
        cout << "What answer do you think it is? ";
        cin >> UI;
        if (UI == intAnswer) {
            lives++;
            cout << "You got it right! You now have " << lives << " lives left " << endl << endl;
            //i = 0;
        }
        else {
            cout << "You got the answer wrong sorry, the correct answer is " << Answer << endl;
            lives--;
            cout << "You now have " << lives << " lives" << endl;
            //i = 0;
            if (lives < 1) {
                cout << "You lose, would you like to play again? 1 for yes, 2 for no? ";
                cin >> opt;
                if (opt = 1) {
                    cout << endl;
                    extra();
                }
                else if (opt = 2) {
                    quiz.close();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    quiz.close();
}


int main() {
int UI;
cout << "Would you like to do the quiz? 1 - yes other - no ";
cin >> UI;
if (UI = 1) {
    extra();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would rethink the way you replay the game. Why don't you put the whole game into an infinite while loop and then break that loop when the user wants to exit? That way you will not need to call the extra() function again, loading the questions again, etc. Plus, when the extra() function finishes it will continue executing the main() function which will exit smoothly with "return 0;".

Comment: Note that `if (UI = 1) extra();` in `main` will always call `extra()`. The test should be `if (UI == 1)`.

Comment: @PeteBecker that is where my issue was!

Comment: @Tylv What I'm suggesting is that the importance of detective skills can't be under-emphasized. *Any* C operator reference states the difference between assignment and equality. It's not that it was a "stupid" question--it's not, it's perfectly reasonable to ask. It's that it's trivially discoverable in essentially any C tutorial/reference, and SO is relatively unforgiving for questions such as this. The onus is on you to research, and in this case, it's easy to do. If it wasn't, I'd suggest finding reference resources now that you can refer to later if similar problems arise. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `main` yourself.
When you call a function and it gets to the end, the function pointer/flow will return to the calling code.

Let's consider the general structure of your code:

```
void extra() {
    for (int i = 0; i = 1; i++) {
                  //^---I suspect you don't mean this, maybe i<1, or 3, or...
                  // recall == and -= are different
            //snipped some details
            if (UI == intAnswer) {
                lives++;
                cout << "You got it right! You now have " << lives << " lives left " << endl << endl;
                i = 0;
            }
            else {
                cout << "You got the answer wrong sorry, the correct answer is " << Answer << endl;
                lives--;
                cout << "You now have " << lives << " lives" << endl;
                i = 0;
                if (lives < 1) {
                    cout << "You lose, would you like to play again? 1 for yes, 2 for no? ";
                    cin >> UI;
                    if (UI = 1) {
                        cout << endl;
                        extra();
                      //^--- I suspect you don't need this recursive call
                    }
                    else {
                        quiz.close();
                        return;
                     // ^---- return back to where we started   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    quiz.close();
    system("pause");
}


int main() {
  int UI;
  cout << "Would you like to do the quiz? 1 - yes other - no ";
  cin >> UI;
  if (UI = 1) {
      extra();//we come back here after the function stops
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note I have simply put `return` where you want to end the function/program.

Comment: Thank you for spotting that for loop error, I fixed it up but for some reason just having that return function **return;** does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does your code actually enter the `else` part? I suspect we've moved on to another question now.

Comment: I want the user to be able to opt out of the game if their lives = 0, when I use the return; function where you placed it, it takes me to the start of extra but not back to main so I can close the program

Comment: `extra` just appears to be called once from `main` Actually you are calling `extra` from inside `extra` so it will return to the last invocation of `extra`

Comment: I now have it working thank you very much I added something after using the return function which caused an error making me believe it didn't work

Comment: Right. Watch out for `-==` and `=` as well

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling main, you can simply return from the `extra` function. The program then continues execution from where you called `extra`.

Comment: Could you please show a code snippet of what you are referring to? I believe I tried that but was still unsuccesful

Answer (score 1):

Just return to `main`.

```
                else {
                    quiz.close();
                    ;
                }
```

Comment: When I use that my game still repeats

Comment: @Tylv: No, the execution returns to `main`, which exits. You're doing something else. Possibly you got a compilation error so that you ran the old executable again.